# batch wildcard (*) in folderpath to target folder name that would vary over time

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to target a folder from batch which potentially will change it's name over time. Say we have `Folder 10102018` next time the batch will be run the folder name would be `Folder 20102018`.

From CMD I am able to navigate to `C:\Fold*` which results in `(C:\Folder 10102018)`
Using the same from a batch file errors as `The system cannot find the path specified.`

The command is -> `"..\..\Folder 1.1.10102018\Install.exe"`

What I try to achieve is to enter that folder using its constant bit of its name "Folder*" and to disregard whatever follows it as it is not really relevant... but hard to work around.

As always appreciate any help or alternative ideas!

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: Wait a minute, I'll ask my crystal ball... please share your relevant batch script part...

Comment: Sorry aschhipfl, I wasn't sure on the dos tag but added it anyway to reach more people. There is not much to share

`"..\..\Folder 1.1.10102018\Install.exe"`

So I'd like this to work instead `"..\..\Folder 1.1.*\Install.exe"`

Comment: You should only add relevant tags. Anyway, this code is more than nothing to share (please [edit] your question and add it there); wildcards (`*`, `?`) can only be used in the *last* element of a path; and they cannot be used to call an application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for (given there is only one matching folder):

```cmd
for /D %%I in ("..\..\Folder 1.1.*") do "%%~I\Install.exe"
```

Wildcards can only be used in the *last* element of a path, and they cannot be used at all to run an application.

Open a command prompt window, type [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)`/?` and read the help text to learn what `for [/D]` does.

Comment: That's great, worked as expected, thanks a lot for that, and I will never mix dos and batch again, I promise! Do you mind explaining what `%%~I` does? Thanks a lot

Comment: `for /D` iterates through all folders that match the given pattern, which is quoted here to avoid trouble with _spaces_; `%%I` is the loop meta-variable that expands to a found folder per loop iteration, including (potential) double-quotes; `%%~I` expands to the same as `%%I` but with surrounding double-quotes removed, so the final path `"%%~I\Install.exe"` is not double-double-quoted (hence preventing something like `""..\..\Folder 1.1.10102018"\Install.exe"`, which will cause trouble)...

Answer (score 1):

> Wildcards can only be used in the last element of a path, and they cannot be used at all to run an application. @aschipfl

```
cd "..\..\Folder 1.1.10102018\*"
Install.exe
```

one-liner

```
cd "..\..\Folder 1.1.10102018\*" && Install.exe
```

and to pop back up 2 dirs just use `cd ..\..`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of space in the folder name. Can you please remove the space in folder name and try?

or use _ or - instead of space.

You should use " " if space is there in the folder name.

Comment: Hi Crack, I am using "" - this is the command `"..\..\Folder 1.1.10102018\Install.exe"` - I am calling this exe from another folder, going up two folders, then enter the Folder with the version and date.. and something breaks there.

So I'd like this to work instead `"..\..\Folder 1.1.*\Install.exe"`